# Couldn't able to connect to Amazon Dynamo DB, grails

Tags: java, grails, amazon-ec2, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Hi all I have a Amazon DynamoDB with the table name of `test`. I have a grails controller like this :

```
def ec2Test = {
    def tableName = new DescribeTableRequest()
    tableName.setTableName("test")
    def createdTable = amazonWebService.dynamoDB.describeTable(tableName)
    }
```

But when I try to hit this controller I get :

`Requested resource not found: Table: Anto_Testing_Table not found`

Even though I can see in my browser that there is an table name `test` available in aws dynamo DB.. In my grails `config.groovy` I have added the following lines too :

```
grails.plugin.awssdk.accessKey = "xxxxxxx"
grails.plugin.awssdk.secretKey = "xxxxxxx"

grails.plugin.awssdk.region = "ap-southeast-1"
```

Where I'm making the mistake? And I also I tried to create the table, and printed the result  , it look like this :

```
{TableName: Testing table, KeySchema: {HashKeyElement: {AttributeName: name, AttributeType: S, }, }, TableStatus: CREATING, CreationDateTime: Mon Oct 01 12:23:37 IST 2012, ProvisionedThroughput: {ReadCapacityUnits: 10, WriteCapacityUnits: 10, }, }
```

I waited for some 15 min. And refreshed the browser, I couldn't able to see the table haven't created! The code I use for creating table is :

```
String tableName = "Testing Table";
CreateTableRequest createTableRequest = new CreateTableRequest().withTableName(tableName)
                        .withKeySchema(new KeySchema(new KeySchemaElement().withAttributeName("name").withAttributeType("S")))
                        .withProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput().withReadCapacityUnits(10L).withWriteCapacityUnits(10L));
    TableDescription createdTableDescription = amazonWebService.dynamoDB.createTable(createTableRequest).getTableDescription();
    println createdTableDescription
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Aws plugin are you using?

Comment: http://grails.org/plugin/aws this one.

Comment: Are you looking for the table in the same region your created it in (ap-southeast-1)?

Comment: Yes. I'm looking at the `ap-southeast-1` region only. But using the sdk I can access the DB values and work with it. But the creation of such table is not visible in AWS Web UI.

Comment: this really looks like a region issue, you should try to check other regions using the AWS console.